# Use rio_readlineb to read image,but not work

Tags: c, unix, networking

I am trying to make a small `proxy` service.

Now the problem is that I can not show the image from web service.

I use `Rio_readlineb` to read image data back.But it could not show up.

```
 while ((Rio_readlineb(&rio_client, buf, MAXLINE)) !=0){
     Rio_writen(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
 }
```

But when I use `Rio_readnb` to read.The problem is solved.

```
while ((size = Rio_readnb(&rio_client, body, MAXLINE)) != 0)
        Rio_writen(fd, body, size);
```

I do not know where is the problem.

readnb

```
ssize_t rio_readnb(rio_t *rp, void *usrbuf, size_t n) 
{
    size_t nleft = n;
    ssize_t nread;
    char *bufp = usrbuf;

    while (nleft > 0) {
    if ((nread = rio_read(rp, bufp, nleft)) < 0) 
            return -1;          /* errno set by read() */ 
    else if (nread == 0)
        break;              /* EOF */
    nleft -= nread;
    bufp += nread;
    }
    return (n - nleft);         /* return >= 0 */
}
```

rio_readlineb

```
ssize_t rio_readlineb(rio_t *rp, void *usrbuf, size_t maxlen) 
{
    int n, rc;
    char c, *bufp = usrbuf;

    for (n = 1; n < maxlen; n++) { 
        if ((rc = rio_read(rp, &c, 1)) == 1) {
        *bufp++ = c;
        if (c == '\n') {
                n++;
            break;
            }
    } else if (rc == 0) {
        if (n == 1)
        return 0; /* EOF, no data read */
        else
        break;    /* EOF, some data was read */
    } else
        return -1;    /* Error */
    }
    *bufp = 0;
    return n-1;
}
```

Is the `rio_readlineb` cut off the data? But If `MAXLINE` is too small,`rio_readnb` also will cut off the data.So where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to implement a HTTP 1.0 proxy.

`rio_readlineb` is looking for the newline character (`\n`, hex value 0x0A, decimal value 10) in the data is is reading. When it has read that character, it returns successfully, indicating the number of characters read. This works fine for reading textual data, like HTTP headers, where each header line is terminated by the newline character.

However, image data is not terminated by a newline character. In fact, images can contain this character anywhere within their data. The moment `rio_readlineb` finds `\n` in the image data, it returns, but the buffer likely does not contain the entire image yet. So, you're sending a corrupt image (too short) to the proxy client.

In HTTP 1.0, the server writes the response headers and then data to the socket. After it has written all the data, it closes the socket. You need to read until end-of-file to get all the image data. This is what your `Rio_readnb` & `Rio_writen` loop is doing.